# What happens if I enable blockfilterindex on an already pruned and synced node?

Tags: pruning, compact-client-side-block-filters

What happens if I enable blockfilterindex on a pruned node that is already synced to tip? Am I able to do this? Does it essentially trigger another IBD to build the filters? Is the node usable / fully operational (other than blockfilterindex related features) during the sync? Or does it not allow me to do this in the first place?